# Scan for unused resources in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-resources, lint, android-studio-3.0

Lint - Scan for Unused Resources - does not work on Android Studio 3.0.  This is CMD-Alt-Shift I (Unused Resources).  It works fine on Android 2.3.3.

In Android Studio 3.0, it just shows "No suspicious code found." message while I know for a fact that there are unused resources on my project.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem in Android Studio 3.0.0 and 3.0.1, however updating to Android Studio 3.1.0 fixed the issue. Now it's working perfectly again.

Comment: It's not working for me in android studio 3.2.1. Anybody experiencing that issue?

Comment: I have the same problem with android studio 3.5